# invalid syntax on int(number) on a try statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first Project that i have to accomplish from the tutorial im currently facing.So here is the Problem i have.I am trying to use collatz(number) in order to get the collatz sequenze.I tryd to find a  similar Problem on stackoverflow but nothing i could relate to (or rather me not understanding it maybe).The error occurs on the second int part.An invalid syntax error occurs on it. I checked everything i could think of(checked all spaces inbetween also changed "except" to "else" because i had trouble there) and than this problem occurred.I also tried to get another paranthese on  **else int((number)) %2==1:** but that didn't help either. i hope you have enough information to help me out.Thank you very much for your Time.

```
 def collatz(number):
   number=input()
   try:
       if int(number) %2==0:
           print('hi')

   else int(number) %2==1:
           print(int(number*3+1))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: You may also want to look into the difference between `else` and `elif` and python is indentation sensitive. Also you are passing in the `number` and then redefining it with `input()`.

Comment: yes ive read python is indentation sensivtive thats why i looked over it dozens of times until i was sure its wasnt that problem. i had except instead of else in it at first . i actually changed else to elif now and added except at the try intendation so it worked now. the visualization helped me a lot right now. but appearently print(int(number*3+1)) is also wrong since i need an str. but thank you for the post. it actually helped me

Comment: `print` doesn't need a string but `int()` expects one - your parens are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix your code as described:

```
def collatz(number):
    number = input()         # number is passed in - doesn't make sense to get it again
    try:
        number = int(number) # Just interpret once
    except ValueError:       # try must have an except clause
        return               # exit on error

    if number%2 == 0:
        print('hi')
    elif number%2 == 1:      # Don't really need an elif - %2 can only have 2 values
        print(number*3+1)
```

However, you may want to look into using a generator (`yield`):

```
def collatz(number):
    while number > 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number //= 2
        else:
            number = 3*number + 1
        yield number

def collatz_series():
    try:
        number = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        return

    for n in collatz(number):
        print(n)
```